# manage.py syncdb error while Django model using non-ascii verbose_name

Tags: python, django, syncdb, manage.py

I am pretty new to Django.

I want the name of my models to be displayed in Chinese, so i used verbose_name in my meta class of my model, codes below:

```
#this models.py file is encoded in unicode

class TS_zone(models.Model):
    index = models.IntegerField()
    zone_name = models.CharField(max_length=50);
    zone_icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='zone_icon', null=True)
    is_active = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=7,choices=SETTING_STATUS_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('index',)
        verbose_name = u'你好嗎？'
        verbose_name_plural = u'你們都好嗎？'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.zone_name
```

However when i run manage.py syncdb, the following errors throws:

```
File "E:\pythonroot\myproject\..\myproject\myapp\models.py", line 19
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe4' in file
E:\pythonroot\myproject\..\myproject\myapp\models.py on line 19, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

It seems that manage.py cannot process non-ascii character in my verbose_name. Anything i have done wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify an encoding. Add the following line as the first line of your `models.py` file.

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

**Update**

The OP has edited his question to say that the "`models.py` is encoded in Unicode". Then the error is strange. It works for me using Django 1.2.1, Python 2.6.2 on Ubuntu Jaunty.

**Update 2**

Can you post the encoding string you have used for your `models.py`?

Comment: It works fine after i added "# encoding: utf-8" , thank you very much.

Comment: There's no such thing as 'encoding in Unicode'. Unicode is *not* an encoding.