# Django username allow non ascii charactors

Tags: python, django

Django username is not allow non-ascii, is there any way to overwrite username in modelform, then it accpets non-ascii charactor?

```
class RegiForm(ModelForm):
username = forms.CharField()
password=forms.CharField(label=(u'password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
password2=forms.CharField(label=(u'password2'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))

def clean_username(self):
```

Comment: What is the Traceback in your console?

Comment: similar? [stack link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656119/manage-py-syncdb-error-while-django-model-using-non-ascii-verbose-name) There's also information on the [django-link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/) if I'm following you correctly.

Comment: it throw a form.username.error in template. it won't validate non-ascii character as an username

Comment: probably should cast a glance over this link - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20694

Comment: you mean add this line in username validators=[ validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[\w.@+-]+$', flags=re.UNICODE), _('Enter a valid username.'), 'invalid'), it doen't help neither